# Passing Values for variable

Tags: powershell

I have written a function which connects to db and gets the details.

```
function ParametersingData {
   param([string]$tablename)

   $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
   $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=servername; Database=dbname; Integrated Security=true"
   $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
   $SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from $tablename"

   $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

   $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
   $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

   $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
   try {
          $rowcount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
   } catch [Exception] {
          Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
   }

   return ()
}
```

I am calling the function in the script file which looks like below

Script:

```
  Data $(ParametersingData)
```

When I run the file, it prompts me to supply values for the tablename and once it is given, the script works as fine. But, I wanted to know, if there is any way that I can provide the tablename in the script file which will avoid asking to supply for tablename.
Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you should read these help files 
[get-help about_command_syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847867.aspx)
and 
[get-help about_parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847824.aspx).

Now, you could try this :
`Data $(ParametersingData "yourtablename")`
or 
`Data $(ParametersingData -tablename "yourtablename")`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The get-help about_parameters also is a very great help.